# Image display with checkbox

Tags: javascript

I want the user to be able to display images by selecting the image that they want to display using a checkbox. I have tried to do that but the image doesn't seem to display when selected

```js
function testdisplay() {
  var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
  var src2=image[2].getAttribute("src");
  var img1 = document.getElementById("check-option8");
  var bg = document.getElementById("container");
    if (img1.checked) {
      bg.src=src2

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img id="dolphin1" class="dolphin" src="../images/dolphins/image1.png" alt="dolphin 1" title="dolphin 1">
  <img id="dolphin2" class="dolphin" src="../images/dolphins/image2.png" alt="dolphin 2" title="dolphin 2">
  <img id="dolphin3" class="dolphin" src="../images/dolphins/image3.png" alt="dolphin 3" title="dolphin 3">
</div>

<div id="toggle-components">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose image to display</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option1" checked="checked"><label for="check-dolphin1">diving down</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option8" onclick="if(this.checked){testdisplay()}" )><label for="check-dolphin8">jumping up</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option5"><label for="check-dolphin5">take off</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option3"><label for="check-dolphin3">jumping together</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try looking at your console to see what error messages are being displayed and then figure out what is causing them. (Hint: `check-dolphin8` doesn't exist)

Comment: I've made changes to my javascript but still, nothing display. Also, I am not getting anything from the console

Comment: You seem to not have a full understanding of the basics of HTML and the DOM; you might want to look at some tutorials and read up on those functions. For example, [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) requires a **tag** name -- something like `div`, `a`, or as required in this case, `img`. You are using `"src"`, which is an *attribute* of the `img` *tag*.

Comment: okay, I have updated my function but the image is still doesn't display. In the console, it shows the image attribute but the image doesn't display.

Comment: How do you expect the image to be displayed? Your code now is setting the `src` attribute on a `div` element, which doesn't support that attribute, so it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to update you code, so that you can understand easily:

Major changes in your code is:

- make an array to keep the image source
- make some changes testDisplay function too.

link of [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dupinderdhiman/ygvphmxq/26/)

```js
var imgArray = [];
imgArray.push("http://reviewnepal.com/socialevents/thumb/google_photo.jpg");
imgArray.push("http://reviewnepal.com/socialevents/thumb/google_photo.jpg");
imgArray.push("http://reviewnepal.com/socialevents/thumb/google_photo.jpg");

function testdisplay() {
  var src2 = imgArray[1];
  var bg = document.getElementById("container");
  if (document.getElementById("check-option8").checked)
    bg.src = src2;
  else
    bg.src = "";
}
```

```html
<img id="container" />

<div id="toggle-components">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose image to display</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option1" checked="checked"><label for="check-dolphin1">diving down</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option8" onclick="debugger; testdisplay();" )><label for="check-dolphin8">jumping up</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option5"><label for="check-dolphin5">take off</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check-option3"><label for="check-dolphin3">jumping together</label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```